# Xcode: How to programmatically make the metal part on my model look real?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

I'm new to Scenekit. Right now I'm trying to display a 3D model with some metal parts on it. After setting all the materials programmatically using:

```
myNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "albedo.jpg")
//... same with metallic map, normal map, roughness map ...
```

the metal parts appear plain white. How should I fix this?

Comment: Btw I only see diffuse, metallic, roughness, normal maps in my texture folder.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read what constitutes a good question in the help section. Abstract questions like this that require a tutorial style answer are generally not answered. If you can refine your question to a specific issue, that would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response by Warren.

It seems that

```
myView.scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents = ...
```

is what I was looking for.

The trick is to set proper backgrounds so that we could see realistic reflections on the metal parts. I was doing it the wrong way using

```
scene.background.contents = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "background.jpg")
scene.lightingEnvironment.contents = UIImage(named: "env.hdr")
scene.lightingEnvironment.intensity = 3

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased

material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "albedo.jpg")
material.metalness.contents = UIImage(named: "metalness.jpg")
material.roughness.contents = UIImage(named: "roughness.jpg")
material.metalness.intensity = 0.5
material.roughness.intensity = 1.0

// YOU CAN ASSIGN ALL THE MATERIALS AT ONCE
node.geometry?.materials = [material]
```